# $0=2x^4+4x^2y^2+6x^2+y^2+xy^2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Solve $0=2x^4+4x^2y^2+6x^2+y^2+xy^2$.

I have found $x=0$, $y=0$, and I believe there are no other solutions. However, how can I prove that this solution is the only one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you mean real solutions.

$ 2x^4 $ and $ 6x^2 $ are always non-negative.  This leaves you with three more terms.  Factor out the $ y^2 $ and these are $ y^2(4x^2 + x + 1) $, which is also non-negative.  So you have

$ 2x^4 + 6x^2 + y^2(4x^2 + x + 1) $

which is non-negative number plus non-negative number plus non-negative number.  (For the last one, you have to check that the quadratic discriminant is negative, which is is.)

Answer (score 0):

We have $2x^4 +6x^2+ y^2\cdot(4x^2+x+1)=0$.

If $4x^2+x+1=0$, then $x=0$ for the expression to be $0$, but $x\neq0$ if the quadratic is $0$, so we can assume $4x^2+x+1\neq0$.

Then, we get $$y^2=-\frac{2x^4+6x^2}{4x^2+x+1}$$All solutions will be of this form. Note that for there to be a real non-trivial solution, $4x^2+x+1<0$, but that doesn't happen for real $x$. So $(0,0)$ is the only real solution. There are other solutions, like $(-1,\sqrt2i)$.